# subtraction between rows in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':['x','y'], 'b':[25,23]},index=[0,1])
```

I just want to perform a simple subtraction between rows

```
df.b[df.a=='x']-df.b[df.a=='y']
```

But I get this output

```
0  NaN
1  NaN
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Vedang Mehta: Just the solution for that subtraction, in my example that is 2

Comment: The row subtraction is aligning on the index and because it doesn't match you get `NaN` result. Even if you could do this it's a little ambiguous what should be returned, the index of the lhs or the rhs, the index of the combined series (which is what it's showing now) so it depends on your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), because both `df` have different indexes:

```
print (df.b[df.a=='x'])
0    25
Name: b, dtype: int64

print (df.b[df.a=='y'])
1    23
Name: b, dtype: int64

print (df.b[df.a=='x'].values - df.b[df.a=='y'].values)
[2]
```

If change index `s2` by index of `s1`:

```
s1 = (df.b[df.a=='x'])

s2 = pd.Series(df.b[df.a=='y'].values, index=s1.index)

print (s1)
0    25
Name: b, dtype: int64

print (s2)
0    23
dtype: int64

print (s1 - s2)
0    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!